# How to handle UICollectionView in UITableViewCell with MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm, uicollectionview

I’m working on an app that has the following View Hierarachy:

`ViewController` -> contains `UITableView` -> contains `CustomTableViewCell` -> contains `UICollectionView` -> contains `CustomCollectionViewCell`

Now I've created a `ViewModel` corresponding to the `ViewController`. The `ViewModel` contains the model objects for `CustomTableViewCells`, i.e. the number of `CustomTableViewCells` to show and what content to show in each `CustomTableViewCell`.

```
class ViewModel
{
    //MARK: Private Properties
    private var libraries = [Library](){
        didSet{
            self.reloadTableViewClosure?()
        }
    }

    //MARK: Internal Properties
    var reloadTableViewClosure: (()->())?
    var numberOfLibraries: Int{
        return self.libraries.count
    }

    //MARK: Internal Methods
    func getLibrary(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Library
    {
        return self.libraries[indexPath.row]
    }

    //MARK: Initializer
    init()
    {
        self.fetchLibraryList()
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods
    private func fetchLibraryList()
    {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "LibraryList", ofType: "json")
        {
            if let libraryList = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Library].self, from: Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)))
            {
                self.libraries = libraryList
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how should I handle `UICollectionView` with MVVM?

1. Should I make the main `ViewController` the delegate & dataSource for both `UITableView` & `UICollectionViews`?
2. Where should I keep the model objects for `CustomCollectionViewCells`? In the same `ViewModel` or should I make a different one?

Comment: Note there's no need to ask readers if they need more info (they know to ask) and we ask that questions trim out chat and niceties (we prefer neutral technical writing here). I often post this advice: _We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i can figure out in this situation is as below,

You should create 3 `ViewModels`

1. **ViewModel** for `ViewController`
2. **CustomTableViewCellViewModel** for  `CustomTableViewCellView`
3. **CustomCollectionViewCellViewModel** for `CustomCollectionViewCellView`

And here is how your `ViewModels` should look like,

```
class ViewModel
{
    private var cellVMs = [CustomTableViewCellViewModel] = []

    var reloadTableViewClosure: (()->())?

    var numberOfLibraries: Int {
        return self.cellVMs.count
    }

    func getLibraryCellVM(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CustomTableViewCellViewModel
    {
        return self.cellVMs[indexPath.row]
    }

    //MARK: Initializer
    init()
    {
        self.fetchLibraryList()
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods
    private func fetchLibraryList()
    {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "LibraryList", ofType: "json")
        {
            if let libraryList = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Library].self, from: Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)))
            {
                libraryList.forEach({
                    cellVMs.append(CustomTableViewCellViewModel(library: $0))
                })
                self.reloadTableViewClosure?()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your `CustomTableViewCellViewModel` will look like this,

```
class CustomTableViewCellViewModel {

        var booksVMs: [CustomCollectionViewCellViewModel] = []

        var library: Library!

        init(library: Library) {
            self.library = library

            // Initialize booksVMs
            library.books.forEach({
                booksVMs.append(CustomCollectionViewCellViewModel.init(book: $0))
            })
        }

        var numberOfBooks: Int {
            self.booksVMs.count
        }

        func bookViewModel(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CustomCollectionViewCellViewModel {
            return self.booksVMs[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
```

and finally `CustomCollectionViewCellViewModel` will look like this,

```
class CustomCollectionViewCellViewModel {

   var book: Book!

   init(book: Book) {
     self.book = book
   }

   var bookName: String? {
      return self.book.name
   }
}
```